# Improve sillcock position

Tags: plumbing

I have a sillcock with the vent oriented at about 8:00 (threads at 2:00). I cannot easily rotate the external parts of the sillcock. I would like the unit to be oriented with the vent and threads perpendicular to the ground to relieve bends in hoses connected.

Is there a solution other than resetting the entire apparatus?[image: sillcock angled oddly]

Comment: Doesn't the sillcock need to be upright to drain properly?

Comment: @Harper I think it may.

Comment: That drain is a back flow preventer and yes it needs to be upright to work properly

Comment: Would the threads where the sillcock attaches to the house plumbing be at or outside the concrete block foundation or would they be inside the concrete block wall (for freeze resistance)? Where is this property located?

Comment: @JimStewart I took off the external plate and did not see threads. The house is in Seattle.

Comment: This appears to be a pier and beam foundation with a crawl space. You should go in the crawl space and see how the sillcock is connected to the house plumbing.  Although it *could* be a sweat joint (soldered), it is probably a threaded connection, and whoever installed it was trying to keep turning it clockwise into the correct orientation but it got fully tight before it got there, and he just left it perhaps intending to come back and correct it.

Comment: What do you mean "the external plate"?

Comment: I suppose that the supply to this sillcock could be above the foundation and inside the wall. In that case I would suppose it is a threaded connection meant to be made from the outside. If this is the case, then if there is a shut-off valve for this faucet turn off the water to this faucet. Now unscrew it CCW counting the number of turns needed. Apply thread sealant (Teflon tape or pipe "dope") and thread the sillcock back on, stopping when it is vertical and is turned a sufficient number of turns to be secure and not leak.

Comment: There might be a cut-off valve to this sillcock in the crawlspace.

Comment: One other possibility is that the sillcock was not fully tightened and you could just turn it CW to the correct orientation. Of course if it is tight and you turn it hard CW you could break it and have pressurized water spraying all over.  NB you have to understand where on the sillcock to wrench. If you apply pressure at the wrong place, you could damage the sillcock.

Comment: @JimStewart The area inside the house is a basement with unfinished floor and insulated ceiling. I will try to see how much of the insulation I would destroy to look for threads.

Comment: What is the light colored material behind the sillcock? metal flashing or wood siding? Is this located below a window?

Comment: @JimStewart metal flashing. It is under a window a distance of 1.5'.